# Build form in tableviewcontrol in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am looking for a tutorial to build a form in tableviewcontrol using row/cell property in ipad. All I can find are tutorials using iPad numbers. Any links to such tutorial where I can build form in tableview control row/cell by adding properties like textbox, pop over, pickerview etc ?

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's advanced TableView [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009111).
 If you want input fields inside of your table, then find your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and add your UITextField or UITextArea or whatever input you want as a subview of the cell.

Comment: I tried working on it. But how do I put PickerView control inside it ?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a pickerView inside of a tableViewCell.  Basically, a pickerView IS a specialized tableView.  So you'd need 2 tableView delegates.  It's not impossible, but if you're just starting out, that's a fairly advanced piece of code to tackle.  Why do you want to embed a picker inside a table cell?

Comment: I am building a form based on XML Config file. The form may contain requirement of selecting say State/Sex/Birthdate, in that case I will need to populate pickerview in table row/cell. I have been able to get label, textfield etc properties but stuck with pickerview.

Comment: [cell addSubview:MyPickerViewController.view];  //Are you doing this?  If not, what code do you have so far?